# How do I use my own function in a timer class?

Tags: winforms, timer, c++-cli

The code is taken from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

```
private:
   static System::Windows::Forms::Timer^ myTimer = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer;
   static int alarmCounter = 1;
   static bool exitFlag = false;

   // This is the method to run when the timer is raised.
   static void TimerEventProcessor( Object^ /*myObject*/, EventArgs^ /*myEventArgs*/ )
   {
      myTimer->Stop();
      
      // Displays a message box asking whether to continue running the timer.
      if ( MessageBox::Show( "Continue running?", String::Format( "Count is: {0}", alarmCounter ), MessageBoxButtons::YesNo ) == DialogResult::Yes )
      {
         
         // Restarts the timer and increments the counter.
         alarmCounter += 1;
         myTimer->Enabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
         
         // Stops the timer.
         exitFlag = true;
      }
   }
```

For example, after the line `myTimer->Stop();` I want to use my own method. How do I identify it? E0020 ID "draw 1" is not defined.

```
 System:: Void Practform::MyForm::draw1() {
   . . .
}
```

Please tell me, because I'm a little stalled, since I've never worked with this.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that what you are bumping up against is attempting to invoke an instance method from a static method. To do so, you would need to have an instance of the class which has the method, e.g:

```
ref struct Foo {
  void InstanceMethod() {}

  static void StaticMethod() {
    auto instance = gcnew Foo();
    instance->InstanceMethod();
  }
}
```

called like so:

```
Foo::StaticMethod();
```

However, taking the [example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#examples), it could be easier (and more appropriate) to change the static methods to instance methods, like so:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

ref struct MyForm : Form {
  Timer ^myTimer = gcnew Timer();

  MyForm(void) {
    myTimer->Tick += gcnew EventHandler(this, &MyForm::TimerEventProcessor);
    myTimer->Interval = 5000;
    myTimer->Start();
  }

  void TimerEventProcessor(Object ^, EventArgs ^) {
    myTimer->Stop();
    draw1();
  }

  void draw1() {
    MessageBox::Show("Done", "Timer is done", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
  }
};
```

called like so:

```
auto form = gcnew MyForm();
form->Show();
```

Notes:

- I'm assuming that you've added the code from the example into your own class, called `MyForm`
- I've used `struct` throughout instead of `class` to make everything `public` - you should use the appropriate access modifiers to your use case

The most notable change is the use of the [`EventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler) constructor which takes an instance of the handler as its first argument, and the method to execute as its second.

The advantages of using instance methods and properties are that:

- you will have access to `this` in the `draw1()` method (given the name of the method, is likely to want to draw using the form instance), and
- the `Timer` instance will be garbage collected as appropriate,